# capybara-webkit flakiness not seeing spinner that's always there?

Tags: capybara, capybara-webkit

I have a single page angular app with a rails backend.  There are links on the page which trigger state transitions (navigating to a page), these toStates throw up a spinner as there is an api call in the background.  Initially, the results of the tests were incredibly flakey because sometimes the api call happened instantly, and sometimes there was a bit of a delay, and capybara would go asserting that stuff was on the page before it was actually there.

To solve this problem, I made it so that my test environment has a hard coded spinner delay that causes all api call spinners to last a minimum of 1000ms.

So, I made a capybara helper method to let me know when the test should move forward with asserting that stuff is actually on the page and ready to be tested:

```
def with_spinner_expectations
  expect(page).to_not have_selector('.spinner')
  yield
  expect(page).to have_selector('.spinner')
  expect(page).to_not have_selector('.spinner')
end
```

so I can do something like:

```
with_spinner_expectations
  page.find('.thing-that-triggers-a-state-change').click
end
```

So, the test would expect there's no spinner, then clicking on the element would transition to the new state and upon that state's controller initialization, an api call is made-- the spinner is shown, and then after 1 second, it goes away.

However, every 5-10 spec runs, it will fail saying there is no selector '.spinner'.........

I even had a problem like this where I am visiting a url which throws up a spinner every time.

```
visit foo_path
expect(page).to have_selector '.spinner'
expect(page).to_not have_selector '.spinner'
```

... It would pass most of the time, but every so often, it would fail, claiming there is no spinner.

If anyone can help guide me on how to make these tests less brittle, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What do you have Capybara.default_max_wait_time (default_wait_time prior to capybara 2.5) set to?

Comment: I tried increasing to 6 seconds and get the same results.

Comment: and by same results I mean totally inconsistent results.

Answer (score 0):

I work in an angular app that also uses a spinner during api calls and use a method like this one:

```
def check_page_done
  begin
    (0..30).each do |i|
      if page.has_css?('#loading-bar-spinner', :wait => 2) then sleep 2 else break end
      puts 'Loading spinner never finished' if i == 30
    end
  rescue Exception => msg
    puts msg
    retry
  end
end
```

The method will wait 2 seconds for a spinner to show up, then move on.  If it does find the loading spinner, it waits another 2.  If the spinner just keeps going and going for a whole minute, then we break so we're not stuck indefinitely.

The exception handling is there because sometimes I run into the dreaded stale element exception, which is easily ignored in this case since we're just dealing with a spinner.

I use this method in a lot of other helper methods, as well as between steps where I know that the regular capybara finders might not be sufficient.

Also have you tried to watch the actual test execution?  Perhaps the spinner really isn't appearing every so often.

Comment: Yeah, the spinner is always there when I watch it with selenium.  It's hard coded in the test environment to always be there for a minimum of 1 second.  It's just capybara-webkit which is flakey and doesn't see it for some reason.  I suppose I need to do more experimenting with screenshots to understand what it is seeing.

Comment: Since you have an artificial delay already set in there, I would maybe up it to 2000ms and see if you end up with more consistent results.

Comment: What kind of driver are you using?  ChromeDriver, Firefoxdriver, headless..?  Perhaps try experimenting and seeing if one proves to be more consistent than the other.

Comment: Sorry - just saw you're using webkit.  You can still try using other drivers though and see if you get more success there.  They're easy to swap in and out.

Comment: I was using poltergeist, but am switching over to webkit as its around 4-6x faster.